# Delphi convert xls to csv by using OleObject

Tags: delphi

I'm studying about how I can convert xls to csv from a file loaded with an openDialog object by using OleObject and two variable (type variant).

```
procedure TForm1.btnConvertXLStoCSVClick(Sender: TObject);

var
openDialog2  : TOpenDialog;
 xls, xlw : variant;
begin
 openDialog2 := TOpenDialog.Create(self);
try
openDialog2.InitialDir := GetCurrentDir;
openDialog2.Options := [ofFileMustExist];
openDialog2.Filter := 'CSV FILE |*.xls';
openDialog2.FilterIndex := 2;
if openDialog2.Execute then
begin
  aFile.LoadFromFile(openDialog2.FileName);
  showMessage('File : '+openDialog2.FileName);

  xls := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  xlw := xls.WorkBooks(openDialog2.FileName);
end;
finally
 //free 
 end;
end;
```

The problem is at the line xls := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application'); After compile it gives this error string interface not valid. ProgId = 'Excel.Application'.

Comment: Do you have Excel installed? Can you find in the registry the key "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Application"?

Comment: I've not already installed it.

Comment: Then you cannot use it! Excel is not built into Windows nor into Delphi. You must install it.

Comment: Instead of freeing the *form* in the end (`Free` means `Self.Free` and since we are in a method of `TForm1`, `Self` is the current instance), free `openDialog2`: `openDialog2.Free`.

Comment: You cannot automate Excel when Excel is not installed, just like you can't drive your car to the store if you don't have a car. Why would you expect to be able to create an object of type `Excel.Application` when you know that you don't have the Excel application installed on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

You must first install Excel to be able to successfully call `CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');`.

Comment: This question should be closed as a typo or non-repro rather than answering it. (Not downvoting - just pointing it out.)

Comment: IMHO this is a misunderstanding, not a typo: this seems fine as a question, and explains the error message.